# UITableViewController, после парсинга JSON и формирования массива из него, задать эту информацию для отображения

Tags: swift, uitableview

Скопирую сначала код весь, а потом пройдусь по нему

```
class Regions: UITableViewController {

    let arr = ["ddd","sss"]

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        tableView.register(UITableViewCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: "myCell")
        ViewHelper.WaitingIndicator.indicatorStart(vc: self, view: view.self)
        Alamofire.request("http://app.com.ua/reference/regions").validate().responseJSON { response in
        switch response.result {
        case .success(let value):
            let json = JSON(value)
            let success = json["success"].stringValue
            print(success)
            var regions = [String]()
            var ids = [String]()
            for (_,subJson):(String, JSON) in json["data"] {
                let id = subJson["id"].stringValue
                let name = subJson["name"].stringValue
                regions.append(name)
                ids.append(id)

            }
            print(regions)
            print(ids)
            ViewHelper.WaitingIndicator.indicatorStop()
        case .failure(let error):
            print(error)
            ViewHelper.WaitingIndicator.indicatorStop()
        } 
    }
}

override func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
    return 1
}

override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return arr.count
}
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "myCell", for: indexPath)
    cell.textLabel?.text = arr[indexPath.row]
    return cell
}
```

Как вы видите, для теста я задавал информацию с самого верхнего массива 
`let arr = ["ddd","sss"]` . -

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return arr.count
}

override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "myCell", for: indexPath)
    cell.textLabel?.text = arr[indexPath.row]
    return cell
}
```

Как задать информацию из свежесформированного `regions` массива 
отсюда

```
var regions = [String]()
var ids = [String]()
for (_,subJson):(String, JSON) in json["data"] {
    let id = subJson["id"].stringValue
    let name = subJson["name"].stringValue
    regions.append(name)
    ids.append(id)
}
```

То есть обратиться к нему. При создании в самом верху, 
 на месте `let arr = ["ddd","sss"]` получается обращение к пустому, не заполненному еще джсоном массиву, а в

```
`viewDidLoad()`
```

не обратишься , и `static` тоже не сделаешь
В общем не могу догнать эту элементарщину)

Comment: Немного по-страшному, но для начала чтобы стало понятнее на примере, сделайте Вашу arr переменной: `var arr = ["ddd","sss"]`. В запросе сделайте `self.arr = regions` и `self.tableView.reloadData()`. Должен отобразиться список полученных regions.

Comment: Вы упомянули в своём вопросе, что должен быть ещё другой класс. Однако в приведённом вами коде он только один. Вы не забыли добавить код из другого класса? Или я что-то не так понял?

Comment: @ VAndrJ Ну ничего себе это как нужно извращаться) Спасибо, работает, механизм я понял.  

В андроиде проще)

Comment: @Roman Podymov не правильно сформулировал, согласен. удалю эту часть

Comment: @Romikromikromik не сказал бы, если вникнуть - намного лучше в iOS сделано (чисто субъективное мнение)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вы отображаете информацию в `UITableView`, где в `UITableViewDataSource` отдаете данные из Вашей `arr`

```
var arr = ["ddd","sss"]
```

Затем Вы получаете данные и в `closure` необходимо добавить/заменить данные и затем перезагрузить таблицу:

```
self.arr = regions 
self.tableView.reloadData()
```

И таблица отобразит обновленные данные.